# R - find the intersection of two lists, include similar values too

Tags: r, list, matrix, intersect

I am trying to get the intersection of two lists containing matrices in R, however I want to include very similar matrices too. For example:

```
a = 
    0.012  0.013
    0.055  0.100

b = 
    0.013  0.013
    0.055  0.100

c = 
    0.013  0.014
    0.056  0.101
```

If `a` is in list one, `b` and `c` are in list two, they should all be included in the output intersect-list. I know that `all.equal` is a great function to return `true` in these cases, and `intersect` function returns a list of exactly same matrices found, I just don't know how to combine them to get the result I want. Thank you for looking into this.

Edit: here is a code that generates example lists of matrices: https://pastebin.com/2yK4sj8G

Comment: Hey ayshelina, could you provide the reproducible example of your data, especially lists with matrices? Otherwise, it's difficult to help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Example added thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible way to compare nearly similar matrices.

```
a = matrix(c(0.012, 0.013, 
             0.055, 0.100),2,2,byrow = TRUE)

b = matrix(c(0.013, 0.013, 
             0.055, 0.100),2,2,byrow = TRUE)

c = matrix(c(0.012, 0.014, 
             0.055, 0.100),2,2,byrow = TRUE)

matrix_compare = function(x,y,threshold) {
  return( all( abs(x-y) <= threshold ) )
}
```

We compare that the absolute difference between `all` individual matrix element values are below a threshold:

```
> matrix_compare(a,b,threshold=0.001)
[1] TRUE
```

However, beware of rounding errors, when comparing the difference!

```
> matrix_compare(a,c,threshold=0.001)
[1] FALSE
```

Therefore, one should introduce also a rounding error threshold (`1e-16`) and add it to the desired comparison threshold (`0.001`):

```
> matrix_compare(a,c,threshold=0.001+1e-16)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: thank you, this is a part of the solution but I am having trouble applying this function in a way that it produces a new list of all similar matrices from two input lists of matrices.

Comment: Will it be (i) one matrix vs. a list of matrices, or, (ii) a list of matrices vs. another list of matrices?

Comment: (ii) a list of matrices vs. another list of matrices